# Requesting Image from PHAssets Array causes in memory exception

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, assets, phasset, photosframework

I am using this code to retrieve photos from album using photos framework,
i have successfully retrieved the PHAssets and put it into array, but i am not able to convert it into images, it crashes during the process.

Here is my code,

```
-(void)retrieveAllPhotoSetWithCompletionCallback:(void(^ __nonnull)(NSMutableArray * __nullable asset ,NSMutableArray * __nullable imageArray , BOOL complete))completionCallback{

    self.requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    self.requestOptions.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
    self.requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
    self.requestOptions.synchronous = YES;

    NSMutableArray *assetsArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];
    [fetchResult enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *_Nonnull asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        [assetsArray addObject:asset];
    }];

    PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[assetsArray count]];

    // assets contains PHAsset objects.
//    __block UIImage *ima;
    int i = 0;

    for(PHAsset *asset in assetsArray) {
        // This autorelease pool seems good (a1)
        @autoreleasepool {

            [manager requestImageForAsset:asset
                               targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize
                              contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                                  options:self.requestOptions
                            resultHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {

                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        //you can add autorelease pool here as well (a2)
                    @autoreleasepool {

                        //assetCount++;
                        NSLog(@"started requesting image %i", i);

                        NSError *error = [info objectForKey:PHImageErrorKey];

                        if (error)
                            NSLog(@"Image request error: %@",error);
                        else {
                            NSString *imagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png",i]];
                            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
                            if(imageData) {
                                [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
                                [images addObject:imagePath];
                            }
                            else {
                                NSLog(@"Couldn't write image data to file.");
                            }
                            NSLog(@"finished requesting image %i", i);
                        }
                    } //a2 ends here
                });
            }];
            i++;
        } // a1 ends here
    }
    completionCallback(assetsArray,images,YES);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is with the `requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize` here you are taking the maximum size with that is available in the program. Which results in storing the maximum size image in the RAM. By storing multiple its gonna eat up more memory in RAM and its gonna crash. I resized the targetSize and the memory usage was less than before.